# LWC JS counter variable using setInterval

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, aura

I have a counter number incrementing from 0 to a given number(percentage). I want to increment it in steps of one after every few miliseconds.

```
let count = 0;
let percentage = 99;
let intervalID = setInterval(function (){       
    count++;
    console.log(count)       // prints values from 1 through 99
    if (count === percentage) {
         clearInterval(intervalID);
    }
},200);
```

But the count on the view is not updating

Comment: Hi, welcome to SFSE. Please take a [tour] and read [ask]. Looks like your question is purely about JavaScript and I think you would find much more help on [so].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, sync and async lines are handled differently.
In the JS event loop first sync events are handeled, after which on a diffrent thread, async events are handled.

It becomes important to pass context in JavaScript.

Use `.bind(this)` for your setInterval anonymous function so that context will be maintained.